# Use git-svn with multiple svn repos and branches

Tags: git-svn, branching-and-merging, git-remote

I have a svn branch that I had been working on and decided to start using git-svn to work locally. Now I have two problems. I want to move my work into another svn repository (on the same host) but I'd first like to merge the latest work from trunk. How would I do this with git-svn? Also, how would I continue my work in a separate svn-repo while continually merging work from the original repo? Also, I don't want to checkout the entire history from the original trunk because the project is rather huge. I am new to git and to git-svn, though I've taken a crash course in git branching and I feel confident enough to use advanced commands like rebase and cherry-pick. I mainly need to know how to apply these concepts thru git-svn. Do the svn repos get setup as a git remote somehow? Are there good resources on the net explaining how it works? Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create your Git repo with `git svn init -s <url>`.
2. `git config --edit`, add several `svn-remotes` for each of your Subversion repos. Later you'll use the `-R` option to all git-svn commands to select which `svn-remote` to use.
3. Tweak `svn-remote` branch mappings as needed. Keep in mind that the default `refs/remotes/*` namespace specifies *remote branches* — not Git remotes. <sub>(You'll have just a single `git remote` named `.` which I don't recommend pushing/pulling to/from).</sub>

   You can easily design your remote branches namespace to keep branches from different Subversion repos separated (e.g. `refs/remotes/repoA/*`, `/refs/remotes/repoB/*` etc).
4. `git svn fetch`. This has options to scan history only partially, e.g. starting from a specific revision. Please read the [manpage](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html) on instructions how to do this.

   You can also ignore specific paths and/or branches here.
5. Work with Git as usual, trying to keep your commits as linear as possible. Rebase often. Merge commits are fine (`git-svn` will even set `svn:mergeinfo` property), but holy cow be careful (and read the manpage for caveats). Understand that Git commits with `git-svn-id` tags are **immutable**, and `push -f` won't save you. For example, it's forbidden to amend or rebase already `dcommit`'ed  changes.

> Are there good resources on the net explaining how it works?

By far the best resource is the [manpage](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html). The next after it is [`git-svn` source](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/tree/perl/Git/SVN.pm).